# How can i access/delete a randomly created document id in firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Code for deleting something (not working with this.task.id or this.task)

```
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
docRef.collection('tasks').doc(this.task.id).delete()
```

Comment: Please add some more details about what was not working. do you get an error? is this.task empty or invalid?

Comment: @e-frank no errors are logged to the console, but when i log this.task to the console then I get the task, which is an object with 3 parameters, the title, details, and a boolean representing complete or incomplete.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#python_2

Comment: @MetaProgramming check my answer below. You must first get the task.id before you can delete it. The 3 object params you've listed does not sound like it contains the unique ref required to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not handling the [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with a then or async/await, like the docs indicate `https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data#node.js`.

Also, your code implies the tasks are nested within the individual users document. If this is not the case, you might be referencing the wrong collection entirely. I suggest first doing a `.get().then(res => console.log(res))` for both the user & their task. If you can't get the document, you can't delete it.